# Output from py2exe converted program gets received all at once

Tags: c#, py2exe

I have made a python console script, and converted it to a .exe with py2exe (I have used the `console = ['test.py']` line in my setup file).

The program parses a file, and during the parse it prints out how much of the file it has parsed. Typical output would be:

```
Processing (currently at 1%)
Processing (currently at 4%)
```

etc.
When running the file in a *cmd window* it works just as expected.

I have also created a very small C# WPF program that just runs the parser:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\temp\test.exe");
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);

Task t = new Task(() =>
{
    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
});
t.Start();
```

The `p_OutputDataReceived` handler just sends the received output to a textbox. This works and I have tested it on other programs, and there I get the output from the program when I expect.

**However** when I run my parser (the one created with *py2exe*) I get all outputs just after the parser has finished. So in the end I get all the correct output, but I get them all at the same time...

(note, I don't get one big output, but rather all the expected outputs but still, all at the same time)

---

So to be perfectly clear here:

- If I run the parser from the command window, I get the outputs one by one
- I have tested to run a C# console program instead of the py2exe generated program and that works (I get the outputs one by one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python checks if `sys.stdout` (the program's standard output) is a console. If it is, Python flushes write buffers immediately so the user can see it. Otherwise writes get cached and are outputted all at once:

- when the write buffer is full or
- at program exit.

The logic behind this is better performance, since when redirecting stdout to a file or to other programs, typically no one cares when the output occurs.

**You can fix this** by including `sys.stdout.flush()` in strategic locations in your Python parser script (i.e. directly after printing status line).

Btw: You should be able to observe the same time-delay behavior if you redirect the output of your parser to `more`, for example:

```
C:\temp\test.exe | more
```